# When playing pool, where can I shoot the eight ball to win?

Tags: rules, pool

If there are no balls on the table, other than the eight ball and the cue ball.

In order to win the game, does the player have to shoot the cue ball down the table to hit the eight ball or can the player shoot the eight ball to the nearest pocket?

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport. What kind of pool speciality are you writing about?

Answer (score 3):

Thinking that the application be referred to the game [eights-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-ball), the Regulation provides that the black ball is pocketed after you holed out his 7 balls.

According with [World Pool-Billiard Association](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=114&pagetype=rules) after having pocketed all their balls 7 is necessary, pocket the 8 ball (hit with the cue ball) in the declared hole.

There are several variants of this type of game with special rules, but the standard is what is written above

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to make either the black ball or the cue ball travel any particular distance along, or over or into any particular part of, the table.

If playing a called-shot variant, the black ball must be sunk by a legal shot in the nominated pocket. If playing a no-call-needed variant, the only requirement is sinking the black ball with a legal shot.